# Resize row widths in many tables based on text string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document containing several tables containing both text and photos. The tables all have two columns and several rows, but some have rows which are TEXT | TEXT whilst some are TEXT | PHOTO.

I'd like to search for a specific string within a sentence with a cell, and then change the cell width of both cells within the row. I'd like to repeat this for all rows and all tables.

The idea is to have the TEXT | TEXT rows set up with a longer first column (15cm) and a shorter second column (2.78cm) whilst the TEXT | PHOTO rows stay as they are.

An example of the text string would be the term "Is the".

Before
[image: Before]

After
[image: After]

I get errors

> Next without For

but I have two of each.

```vb
Sub ColumnWidthText1()

    Dim oTbl As Table
    Dim oRow As Row
    Dim TargetText As String

    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then Exit Sub

    TargetText = InputBox$("Is the")

    For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    
        For Each oRow In Selection.Tables(1).Rows
            If oRow.Cells(1).range.Text = TargetText & vbCr & Chr(7) Then
                oRow.Cells(1).Width = InchesToPoints(5.2)
                oRow.Cells(2).Width = InchesToPoints(1.8)
        Next oRow
        
    Next oTbl
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Thanks PEH - I have added code tried to my original post.

Comment: Please also explain what is wrong with the code? What errors do you get? What does it do vs. what did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want might be achieved with code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, r As Long
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  With Tbl
    If .Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
      For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
        If .Cell(r, 2).Range.InlineShapes.Count = 0 Then
          .Rows(c).Cells.DistributeWidth
        End If
      Next
    End If
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Alternatively:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, r As Long
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  With Tbl
    If .Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
      For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
        If .Cell(r, 2).Range.InlineShapes.Count = 0 Then
          .Cell(r, 1).Width = InchesToPoints(5.2)
          .Cell(r, 2).Width = InchesToPoints(1.8)
        End If
      Next
    End If
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help macropod - I really appreciate you coming back to me. I changed the very last "End With" statement to "Next" as I was getting a Compile error when I ran the code: End With without With. The code very nearly does what I was looking for. However, it also changes the column widths in the tables which contain no inline shapes (i.e. text tables) which I was looking to avoid, retaining the original column widths. I've tried  adding an ELSE statement but this counteracts the original code. Please can you help?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Macropod - this works far better than the search string approach I managed to cobble together yesterday evening!